# moz-border-radius,moz-box-shadow in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using moz-boder-radius(-webkit-border-top-left-radius) to add rounded divs to my website.

these work fine in Mozilla, chrome and safari  but as usual Internet explorer have to have some problem.

Is there any such property to add rounded divs in Internet explorer.

Comment: In short: no, there is no such CSS property that would work in Internet Exporer today. Read [this article](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/) for more info.

Comment: MSDN official answer: [Rounded Corners in Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb250413)

Answer (score 1):

This (jQuery plugin) works cross-browser:

http://jrc.rctonline.nl/

This is a standalone version, also works cross-browser:

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/

There's no way to get rounded corners with pure CSS in IE.

Answer (score 1):

The -moz and -webkit properties are experimental, and not an official part of the CSS2. They are really meant to work for just Mozilla (Gecko) browsers, and may be phased out of those browsers too after a time.

I used this, it requires no images or javascript,just css:

http://blog.benogle.com/2009/04/29/css-round-corners/

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS there is no way to do that for IE!

But you can add a conditional comment (`<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->`) with some extra CSS which apply four rounded corner images to a "top" div and a "bottom" div contained in a main div!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use IE version lesser than 9.0.

The `border-radius` CSS property is supported only from IE 9.0 which brings the nice rounded rectangle.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/border-radius

If you need to use rounded rectangle below IE 9.0, you may need to use images to achieve this.