# box-shadow issue in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have following css class

```
.NavNew ul li.current a, .NavNew ul li a:hover, .NavNew ul li:hover
        {
            box-shadow: 0 3px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
        }
```

it works great in mozila but doesn't work in IE.. What is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of questions dealing with this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687804/emulating-css3-border-radius-and-box-shadow-in-ie7-8 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1616976/moz-border-radius-moz-box-shadow-in-ie or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884445/css-shadows-are-fine-with-firefox-and-chrome-but-not-showing-on-internet-explore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE version less than 9 does not support CSS3 `box-shadow` property.

You have to use the proprietary IE `filter` property to achieve the effect.

For some samples on how to achieve it, see [this article](http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/). Also check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for CSS compatibility of IE versions.

Answer (score 4):

Box shadow is a css3 feature... Css3 features are not available for  IE below IE 9.. Please go through the site below  to get the complete knowledge about what all css features are there in which all features of IE...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

```
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 20px 20px 50px 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 20px 20px 50px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 20px 20px 50px 5px;
```

you can see also:

[box shadow one](http://placenamehere.com/article/384/css3boxshadowininternetexplorerblurshadow/)

or

[box shadow two](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)

Answer (score 3):

IE earlier than version 9 doesn't support the `box-shadow`, there is a workaround to use [IE shadow filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to imitate a box-shadow:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color=#ff0000);
```

[reference](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/)